# SQL Query that takes for ever

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build an eCommerce site where you can search with keywords but also using category if you want to. The search takes up to 45 seconds sometimes.   All these years of programming and I can't figure this one out.

Ok I know I won't ever be able to do it as fast as google. Nor do I know how to do an ADVANCED search thing I just want a quicker one line SQL code. And if that's not a problem by it self, I have to run the query AGAIN with count(*) just to get the amount of total rows (for the pages etc).
I don't want to just use like %__% because I want it to search for words. The word(s) they use I want to be searched in multiple columns: "Title, Description, Child_value and colors".
The SQL code below searches for keyword "cable":

```
SELECT `id`,`title`,`colors`, `child_value`, `vendor`,`price`,`image1`,`shipping` FROM `the_table` WHERE `display` = '1' and `category` = '12' 
AND 
 (`title` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)CABLE([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)' 
or 
 `description` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)CABLE([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)'
or 
 `child_value` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)CABLE([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)'
or 
 `colors` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)CABLE([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)') 
AND 
 `display` = '1' and `category` = '12' and (`title` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)'
or 
 `description` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)'
or 
 `child_value` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)'
or 
 `colors` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)') limit 0, 12
```

And this is only if I search for ONE word !!!! If I search for two words "RED CABLE", the SQL becomes even longer!!:

```
SELECT `id`,`title`,`colors`, `child_value`, `vendor`,`price`,`image1`,`shipping` FROM `the_table`WHERE `display` = '1' 
AND 
 `category` = '12' and (`title` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)RED([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)'
or
 `description` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)RED([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)'
or
 `child_value` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)RED([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)'
or
 `colors` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)RED([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)') and `display` = '1' and `category` = '12'
AND 
(`title` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)CABLE([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)'
or
 `description` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)CABLE([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)'
or
 `child_value` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)CABLE([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)'
or
 `colors` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)CABLE([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)') 
AND 
 `display` = '1' and `category` = '12' and (`title` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)'
or
 `description` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)'
or
 `child_value` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)'
or
 `colors` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)') limit 0, 12
```

Imagine if you search for more than 2 words! I know the code is pathetic and just embarrassing!! But I don't know what to do :(

the columns in database:

**ID** = primary

**Title** = varchar(500) and Index

**Description** = Text and Index

**child_value** = varchar(100)

**colors** = varchar(255)

The database has 98565 rows, total of 213 MB
With my ADHD it's so hard to read up though I been trying to find a solution for over a month now. Is there an easier QUICKER way ?

Comment: Remove the inverted commas from around numeric values. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and note that questions about query performance also always require the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REGEXP statement is in comparison with LIKE quite or very slow (depending on the complexity of the regular expression). And you have a lot of REGEXP statements in your query.

To speed up your query, you could **add** LIKE queries to your WHERE clause. A

```sql
`description` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)RED([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)'
```

is never going to match when the following isn't true

```sql
`description` LIKE '%RED%'
```

By filtering out all the rows that doesn't match the LIKE statement, MySQL only needs to perform the (more time expensive) REGEXP statement on the smaller subset of rows (yes, MySQL is smart enough to do this then). So that REGEXP is then only used to distinguish between rows where the description contains "RED", "REDDIT", etcetera and it doesn't need to parse descriptions like "Blue his house, with a blue little window, and a blue Corvette, and everything is blue for him" anymore.

Minimal sample query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `the_table`
WHERE 
    (
        (
            `description` LIKE "%RED%"
            AND `description` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)RED([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)'
        )
        OR
        (
            `title` LIKE "%RED%"
            AND `title` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)RED([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)'
        )
    )
    AND
    (
        (
            `description` LIKE "%CABLE%"
            AND `description` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)CABLE([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)'
        )
        OR
        (
            `title` LIKE "%CABLE%"
            AND `title` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)CABLE([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)'
        )
    )
```

---

Ps. why do you have the

```sql
`description` REGEXP '([[:blank:][:punct:]]|^)([[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)'
```

at the end of the query? It seems a mistake since it is exactly the same as:

```sql
`description` = '' OR `description` REGEXP '[[:blank:][:punct:]]'
```

Comment: Hi Peter. If I have a word "Restaurant" in the title, I don't want this to come up if someone searches for "rant". That's why I'm not using like %__% and using regexp with punct. Because I want it to only search for whole words.  Does your minimal Sample query do just that? =)

Comment: It uses BOTH like AND regexp. So if it doesn't match your (original) regexp, it (still) isn't included in the result. The like part is only there to speed up the query (if it doesn't like %rant% it wouldn't regexp anyway, but the like is a lot faster to check)

Comment: Peter, I'll give it a shot =)    Thank you!!
I'm going to add a LIMIT 0,12 at the end of this. Should I run EXACT same query after without the "limit 0,12" and put "count(*)" to get the TOTAL amount of rows found?

Comment: Yes, that will give the total count

Comment: It just sucks that I gotta do another query run the exact same thing pretty much but just replace the beginning part to count(*). Because the count query it self takes alone takes several seconds :/
I wish there was a way to just get the TOTAL rows from just 1 query that contains limit 0,12 :(